# loop through associative array and passed key in sql query

Tags: php, sql, arrays, codeigniter, associative-array

i have the requirement, when user checks checkbox, i m getting checkbox value as key value pair

```
Array( 
    [checkboxname] => Array( 
           [1] => on 
           [5] => on 
           [12] => on 
           [15] => on 
       )
)
```

i have to pass this key in sql statement and retrive another checkbox from this key.

this is query i have to write

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
        {

        }

$reult = $this->db->get_where('select_another_value ', array('id' => $key))->result_array();
```

what should i write in query instead of `$key`

Comment: what you actually want?all the result of checkboxname?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam when user click parent_checkbox he should see his child_chekbox

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $reult[] = $this->db->get_where('select_another_value ', array('id' => $key))->result_array();
}
```

Or you can try with -

```
$keys = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $keys[] = $key;
}
if (count($keys) > 1) {
    $where = "  id IN (".implode(',', $keys).")";
} else {
    $where = " id = '".$key[0]."'";
}
$this->db->where($where);
```

If you want to avoid running query inside loop.

Comment: you mean `$reult` have only last `key` records??

Comment: @sgt then what should be return statement return $reult[]; or only return $reult;

Comment: Why do you need `return` statement? @SoftwareDev

Comment: @sgt from this query i have to show another checkbox related to this key in db

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to get all checked `check boxes` value from db, and `Id` inside array key and use `where_in()` method and pass array keys in array, see below sample code

```
$all_keys = array_keys($arr['checkboxname']);
$result = $this->db->where_in('id', $all_keys)
      ->get('select_another_value')->result_array();
```

Comment: i know this but what i want is to retrive this key from array `array(key => 'on')`

Comment: ok, try this `reset($arr); $key = key($arr)` if you need first key of array